# Java: How to deep-clone a HashSet neatly?

Tags: java, cloning

I have a HashSet of `MyObject` that I need to clone. If `MyObject` implements a copy-constructor, what is the easiest, neatest way to clone `Set myObjects`

Obviously I could do something like:

```
 Set<MyObject> myNewObjects = new Set<MyObject>(); 
 for(MyObject obj: myObjects) myNewObjects.add(new MyObject(obj));
```

But I'm doing this as part of a loooong copy-construcotr, and I'd really like to just be able to do it in one line like:

```
public myClass(MyClass toClone){
    //... 
    this.myObjects = new Set<MyObjects>(toClone.getmyObjects()); 
    //... 
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: There's also a Clonable interface you can use.

Comment: Hi David, every article I've come across has strongly warned me off using clone(), as it's implementation is inherently broken... do you disagree or was this just an FYI?

Comment: You can always override clone, but yes, it's kinda broken by default.

Comment: There is no fully generic way to deep clone anything in Java.  You will have to use `MyObject`'s constructor directly.

Answer (score 15):

If you are using Java 8, you can do something like this:

```
Set<MyObject> set1 = new HashSet<>();
Set<MyObject> set2 = set1.stream().map(MyObject::new).collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Keep in mind, however, that using [`Collectors.toSet()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toSet--):

> There are no guarantees on the type, mutability, serializability, or thread-safety of the Set returned

Although current implementation in Java 8 Update 5 uses regular HashSet.

Comment: Java 6 legacy system :(

Answer (score 4):

You can use Google Guava's [`Iterables`](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/CollectionUtilitiesExplained#Iterables) to do something like this:

```
Set<MyObject> newSet = new HashSet<MyObject>(
  Iterables.transform(myObjects,new Function<MyObject, MyObject>() {
    @Override
    public MyObject apply(MyObject input) {
      return new MyObject(input);
    }
  }));
```

Or if you want it immutable use [Guava's immutable set](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/ImmutableCollectionsExplained):

```
Set<MyObject> newSet = ImmutableSet.copyOf(
  Iterables.transform(myObjects,new Function<MyObject, MyObject>() {
    @Override
    public MyObject apply(MyObject input) {
      return new MyObject(input);
    }
  }));
```

Unfortunately it does not get any more compact than what you already have unless you can use Java 8.

Comment: @Paul asked for a deep copy.

Comment: Hi Giovanni, I was under the impression that the HashSet Copy constructor would give me a shallow copy? 
I mean, it's not going to call the copy constructors of each element in the set?

Comment: @Paul I didn't realize you were actually creating new instances, my apologies. I'll edit.

Comment: @Paul Please take a look at the edit, and once again apologies for misreading!

Answer (score 0):

```
Set<MyObject> set = new HashSet<>();
        for (MyObject value : myHash) {
            set.add(value.copy());
        }
```

`value.copy()` is the function that clones your object (you need to create a method like that and create a new object and assign the fields accordingly to make deep cloning work.).